# Manipulating ffmpeg Question

Tags: 16.04, git, ffmpeg

I am using Ubuntu 16, and need to manipulate ffmepg source code , then run ffmepg with those alterations.  I have downloaded the source code into a folder from git, and also have installed ffmpeg from the repo (via ffmepg's install instructions for ubuntu).

My question is, how can I manipulate the source code , then run / test ffmepg with those changes ?

The binary (output of "which ffmpeg") is located at /usr/bin/ffmpeg

and the source code folder from git is in a folder on my desktop

according to the install.md file , it seems like this should be able to be accomplished by `/ffmpegdir/ffmpeg/configure` , but when trying this i am greeted with the error nasm/yasm not found or too old.

I have updated from git so i am sure i'm using the most up to date version of ffmpeg (im not completely sure this is the method to accomplish what i want though)

Answer (score 0):

The solution seemed to be installing yasm for me (sudo apt install yasm).

Then

```
<filepath to ffmpegdir>/configure

make

make install
```

Comment: I hope you're using `git` to track your changes.